# Multi threading question

Tags: mysql, vb.net, multithreading

I'm trying to make a server program for a game, I need to run 3 extra threads in a windows form app. all the threads needs to be able to access the same variables, (thread1: is going to be pulling user commands from my database and executing them, thread2: is going to be updating all the users data and thread3: is going to be sending all the new variables back to the database.) I've looked into background threads and I'm not sure if thats going to do what i want them todo (they look like they could run my code but it looks like they would have a hard time working with the same variables for the all the threads.)

So i guess my question is, is this possible and what is best way to accomplish this, would background workers and invoke do the trick? what problems would i be looking at doing that, anyone have any better idea.

On a side note i had another question thats related ive tried a bunch of times to accomplish this using just simple threads. Now from what i understand doing all of my work on another thread should not lock up my ui, however it does. maybe im doing thread the wrong way, my code looks something like

```
dim newthread as new system.threading.thread(addressof runmycode)   
newthread.start()`
```

this code isn't exact but why would using threading like this lock up the UI? Shouldn't it be running separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a 'new' instance of the object class to be 'threaded' and expose the function you want to call, e.g.

```
Public Class MyNewCode
    Public Function runmycode()

        ' My code goes here '

    End Function
End Class


Public Class frmMain ' or under an onClick event or whatever.... '
    Dim s As New MyNewCode ' This is the class above '
    t = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf s.runmycode) ' This is the function above '
    t.start()
End Class
```

Comment: provided this frees up my ui, i think this is exactly what im looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial I wrote a little while back that walks you through creating a basic multi-threading program in VB2008. With VB2010 you can remove the delegates if you want but the idea is pretty much the same.

[Creating a simple multi-threaded VB.Net application](http://chrishaas.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/creating-a-simple-multi-threaded-vb-net-application/)